# How do you create a test server in .NET 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-6.0

I need to write some unit tests for an ASP.NET 6 API and need to create a test server to verify authorization. However since the startup class has been removed, I don't know what I should use as the entry point for the test server creation.
This was the way of creating one in previous versions.

```
 var server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
```

Comment: The fact that the start-up class has been removed to show off the new feature of the language does not mean that you can't put it back.

Comment: The `UseStartup<Startup>()` method is still there, the ASP.NET team just decided to showcase the new language features and add everything to the `Program` file, this doesn't mean you can't put it back, which I urge you to do if you want to re-use code

Answer (score 10):

You can use `WebApplicationFactory` (which, based on [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-6.0), is a wrapper around `TestServer` and exposes properties and methods to create and get it like [`CreateServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1.createserver?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and [`Server`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.testing.webapplicationfactory-1.server?view=aspnetcore-6.0)) for your integration tests. To set up it with the [new minimal hosting model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#new-hosting-model) you need to make you web project internals visible to the test one for example by adding next property to csproj:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <InternalsVisibleTo Include ="YourTestProjectName"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

And then you can inherit your `WebApplicationFactory` from the generated `Program` class for the web app:

```
class MyWebApplication : WebApplicationFactory<Program>
{
    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        // shared extra set up goes here
        return base.CreateHost(builder);
    }
}
```

And then in the test:

```
var application = new MyTestApplication();
var client = application.CreateClient();
var response = await client.GetStringAsync("/api/WeatherForecast");
```

Or use `WebApplicationFactory<Program>` from the test directly:

```
var application = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>()
    .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
       // set up servises
        });
    });
var client = application.CreateClient();
var response = await client.GetStringAsync("/api/WeatherForecast");
```

An alternative to the `InternalsVisibleTo` approach is to just declare `Program` class explicitly as a partial one. For example add the following to the bottom of the top-level statement file (usually `Program.cs`):

```
public partial class Program { }
```

Code examples from [migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-6.0#test-with-webapplicationfactory-or-testserver).

Answer (score 8):

The issue ended up being that by default Program.cs isn't discoverable, so I ended up adding this to the ASP.NET Core .csproj file.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <InternalsVisibleToInclude="{Insert testing project name here}" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And adding

```
public partial class Program { }
```

To the bottom of the Program.cs file